# I want to track device fall using Sensors

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sensors

I am developing an app in that i want to track device fall case. From the study, the simple algorithm can be applied for fall detection by observing any change of x-, y-, or z-acceleration 10g within time limited obtaining from ADLs in terms of lying down. But i want to track that sensors when app is in terminated state.

Does anyone know the way to acceleration when app is terminated.

Comment: You want to make an app that does THIS.  And you want somebody to track THIS?  It doesn't sound like a good topic.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as much as I understand your requirement, these are some points may be it will help you -

1. If your app relies on the presence of accelerometer hardware, configure the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key of its Info.plist file with the accelerometer value.
2. To get the accelerometer data you can try this -

   **var accelerometerUpdateInterval: TimeInterval { get set }**
3. And to Starts accelerometer without a handler you can try this.

   **startAccelerometerUpdates()**

Some help full links -

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616135-accelerometerupdateinterval

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_raw_accelerometer_events

** Some important notes >> Getting the accelerometer data is like getting the location update and location data from device both functions are work like same so keep that in mind when developing any function.